# What's the difference between smbclient and samba?

Tags: samba

I've seen both of them in the repos. What's the difference between them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `apt-cache show samba`:

> This package provides the components necessary to use Samba as a
>   stand-  alone file and print server or as an NT4 or Active Directory
>   domain  controller. For use in an NT4 domain or Active Directory
>   realm, you will  also need the winbind package.  .  This package is
>   not required for connecting to existing SMB/CIFS servers  (see
>   smbclient) or for mounting remote filesystems (see cifs-utils).

whereas, from `apt-cache show smbclient`:

> This package contains command-line utilities for accessing Microsoft 
>   Windows and Samba servers, including smbclient, smbtar, and smbspool. 
>   Utilities for mounting shares locally are found in the package
>   cifs-utils.

For completeness, `apt-cache show cifs-utils` says:

> This package provides utilities for managing mounts of CIFS network
>   file  systems.